# Datetime created in php is not been refreshed in firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, datetime, firefox

I have a star time and i add some minutes. After that i store the new datetime in a new var and I print it. The problem is that when i refresh the page in firefox the new datetime is not printed. On the other hand when i use chrome i can see the new datetime when refreshing the page.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$minutes_to_add = 5;

$start =new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$start->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));

$end = $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $end;
```

Any response will be helpful!

Comment: Try clearing firefox cache and refresh.

Comment: A very common and preferred way to clear a cache or control it is to also append a timestamp to a URL... If its a static/non variable url like bla.html or bla.php without any URL parameters.. Then you will need to apply headers.. But being your using PHP.. sounds like you need to disable cache for development purposes... Google will answer this one easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest clearing your firefox cache. This can be done pressing `CTRL` `+` `F5`.

One more thing, instead of:

```
$start =new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

You could also use:

```
$start = new DateTime('now');
```

Or simply:

```
$start = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is most likely caching the request. You can manually clean your browser cache to see the updated result, but other users that visit your page will experience the same issue.

How browsers cache the requests can be controlled with the HTTP Header you send from your PHP script.

Are you manipulating the cache headers in some way in another php file? The default behavior for browsers would be not to cache your page.

To explicitly tell the browser not to cache your page, use the following PHP code

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

PS: The fact that it works on Chrome and not Firefox might be because you have disabled cache altogether in chrome (for example, by opening the dev tools).